# How to provide a codec to the SaveAsSequenceFile method in Spark?

Tags: java, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am trying to figure out how to pass a codec to the saveAsSequenceFile method in Apache Spark.  Below is the code I am trying to run.  I am running Scala 2.10.4, Spark 1.0.0, Java 1.7.60, and Apache Hadoop 2.4.0.

```
val rdd:RDD[(String, String)] = sc.sequenceFile(secPath,
                                classOf[Text],
                                classOf[Text]
                               ).map { case (k,v) => (k.toString, v.toString)}

val sortedOutput = rdd.sortByKey(true, 1)

sortedOutput.saveAsSequenceFile(secPathOut)
```

My issue is that I am new to Spark and Scala.  I do not understand what the javadoc means for the codec variable passed to the saveAsSequenceFile method.

```
def saveAsSequenceFile(path: String, codec: Option[Class[_ <: CompressionCodec]] = None): Unit
```

What does the <: mean?  I get that the codec is optional, because when I run the above code it works.  Could someone please show an example of a properly formatted codec call to this method?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `<:` indicates that the class you pass in should extend [`org.apache.hadoop.io.compress.CompressionCodec`](http://hadoop.apache.org/docs/current/api/org/apache/hadoop/io/compress/CompressionCodec.html) (read [this](http://www.scala-lang.org/old/node/136)), spark uses a lot of HDFS features and is pretty heavily integrated with it at this point. This means you can pass the class of any of the following as the codec, `BZip2Codec, DefaultCodec, GzipCodec`, there are likely also other extensions of `CompressionCodec` not built into hadoop. Here is an example of calling the method

```
sc.parallelize(List((1,2))).saveAsSequenceFile("path",Some(classOf[GzipCodec]))
```

The `Option[...]` is used in scala in favor of java's `null` even though `null` exists in scala. `Option` can be `Some(...)` or `None`